# Infinite execution of the code in google apps script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, do-while

I have this code wich runs infinitly. I checked step by step and the error is in the last part of it where there is a loop.

I have in cell(f,3) the value 400 and respectively in cell(f,4) cell(f-1,4) cell(f-2,4) cell(f-3,4) : 200, 50, 20, 100

The cell(f,12) should show the value 270.

```
function myFunction() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();      

      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
      var active = sheet.getActiveCell();

      var f = active.getRowIndex();           
      var r = sheet.getRange(f,3).getValues();        
      var i = f          
      var cellule = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValues();      
      var C = 0

      do {            
        C = C + cellule;
        var destverif = sheet.getRange(f,12);      
        destverif.setValue(C);
        i = i-1;            
         }while (C + cellule <= r);      

 }
```

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet with some sample data? It would make this significantly easier. That or post a dataset described in clear A1 notation or col/row index to make it easier to rebuild rather than `I have in cell(f,3) the value 400 and respectively in cell(f,4) cell(f-1,4) cell(f-2,4) cell(f-3,4) : 200, 50, 20, 100`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FyzOrdvQYyZHwa3GFBq_ES_d0j-Qx-U2mNs8j1WcVoo/edit#gid=0  i shared my spreadsheet with you.  i'm testing on it before going on the right spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `getValues()` instead of `getValue()` which returns an array. Your while condition is essentially checking `while(NaN + [["200"]] <= [["400"]])` which will not really work out, it seems as though it was returning true and you had a loop that was essentially `while(true)`.

To correct this, use `getValue()` instead. This immediately corrects your infinite loop.

I chatted with you over gchat and determined your logic was also faulty for the output you expected. You are trying to take a set of data like this:

[image]

Get the value of the highlighted column starting at `200` and going up till your total is greater than or equal to `400`. Once it hits this value, write into column 12 of that row `400 / AVERAGE(200,100,101)`

I corrected your code, this code does the trick:

```js
function getValues(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
  var active = sheet.getActiveCell();  

  var rowIndex = active.getRowIndex(); //Get the rowindex of the current active cell
  var maxValue = sheet.getRange(rowIndex,3).getValue(); //Your max value is the active cells value

  var currentValue = 0;
  var activeRowIndex = rowIndex
  var loopIndex = 0;
  do{

    var cellData = sheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 4).getValue(); //Get the value of the cell next to the selectedCell
    if(cellData !== ''){ //If the cell is not blank continue
      currentValue += cellData; //Add up the total as we go
      activeRowIndex --; //Subtract the row index so we can keep movign up
      loopIndex++; //Iterate the loopIndex so we know how many numbers we have added up to calculate the average
    } else {      
      break; //If the cell is blank, break out of the loop
    }

  } while (currentValue <= maxValue);

  sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 12).setValue(maxValue/(currentValue/loopIndex)); //set the ranges value and do the math in line for the average.
}
```